# Did Google eliminate access to cached sites?

Tags: google-search, cached-webpages

In what seems to be [yet another useful feature Google has apparently and quietly removed](https://www.reddit.com/r/google/comments/4z6bqo/google_silently_removing_features_why/), viewing Google's cached versions of websites appears to now be impossible. Their [documentation is predictably obsolete](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/1687222?hl=en), as a "down arrow" no longer exists in Google's results, and the new three-dot widget pulls up an "About this result" "beta" feature that as far as I know I didn't sign up to be part of.

Is access to Google's caches gone, or is there an undocumented method to access them?

[image: Cache is gone]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click the Cached button in the lower right hand corner of your screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I missed that, thank you! Google needs to update their documentation.

Comment: That cached button is gone, replaced by a button labeled similar. (June 2021) (edit: some links have cached buttons, some don't)

Comment: The way it seems to be going: Google has a lot of cached data already in place, and offers links to that cached data, but it looks like they are moving away from that more and more, not adding new caches. I can find old caches that may have been popular enough to be kept, but not newer ones and not obscure (rarely sought) ones either. I do believe there are a few websites out there like reputation.com that collaborate with google to remove caches that might damage privacy or character.  Most likely this cache feature will slowly disappear, like the controversial live search suggestions have.

Comment: @osirisgothra - What “controversial live search suggestions” ?

Answer (score 8):

Google may [not show a "cache" option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvJC0.png). However, the cache is still usually available if you manually construct the URL, like so:

[https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:**example.com**](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:example.com)

You can also use this bookmarklet I made to automatically go to the cached version of the current page:

```
javascript:location.href="https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:"+window.location
```

Lastly, you can use the query operator `cache:` in front of a URL to go to its cache: `cache:example.com`. You can either type this in the Google search box or your browser bar (assuming that it's configured to do a Google search).

Comment: The [accepted answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/150959/88163) looks to be still up to date for the web search results that I have just reviewed.  Please provide context / source / how did you get to this conclusion. Another possibility I suggest you to consider is to slighty change the wording to avoid generalize the no longer availability of the cached page feature.

Comment: @Rubén It's possible that they're doing A/B testing. On both mobile and desktop I see the [popup with no cache button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvJC0.png). I used to see a cache button on desktop. I never saw it on mobile (except when requesting the desktop version).

Comment: A long time ago I read somewhere in the SO / SE universe *Your mileage might vary*... that is specially true regarding Google Search: it might be a thing of A/B testing, app used (Web, iOS, Android) country domain (.com, .com.mx, .es, etc.) personalized results, ...

Answer (score 4):

Some sites decide to add the do-not-cache tag to the page.  This appears to be common to sites that begin charging for content.